# Meteor Account.createUser TypeError: Cannot read property 'accessToken' of undefined

Tags: meteor, access-token, createuser

I try to create User Registration. I have install

```
accounts-base                              1.2.2* A user account system
accounts-password                          1.1.4* Password support for accounts
```

On client side :

```
var userNew = {
    password: textPassword,
    username: textUserName,
    profile: {
        address: textAddress
    }
};

Accounts.createUser(userNew, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        alert(err.message);
    } else {
        Router.go('/');
    }
});
```

But show error :

```
I20160423-17:47:07.299(7)? Exception while invoking method 'createUser' TypeError: Cannot read property 'accessToken' of undefined
```

Also i have set on server side :

```
Accounts.config({
    forbidClientAccountCreation : false
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I done with update & recreate PROJECT. I dont figure whats the problems. but recreate project solved this problems.
Hopelly its helps others